# A multiple choice question on determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A\in M_{10}(C)$, $\det(A)<0$ and $AA^{t}=I$. Which of the following statements is true about $\det(A+I)$?

(a) $\det(A+I)=-1$

(b) $\det(A+I)=0$

(c) $\det(A+I)> 1$

(d) $\det(A+I)=1$

Comment: Can we use eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: @Ludolila yes, you can use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\det A = \det A^t = -1$ from the given condition. Now, consider $-\det(I+A) = \det (I + A)\cdot \det(A^t) = \det (A^t + I)$ since determinant is multiplicative. But it is obvious that $(A+I)^t = A^t + I,$ so we have $-\det(A+I) = \det((A+I)^t),$ which means that the determinant is $0.$

Answer (score 1):

Nice answer @lyj! I was going to solve it with eigenvalues.

Since $AA^t=I$, $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, and thus $\det{A}= \pm 1$. From the given condition $\det{A}=-1$, which means that $A$ is a reflection matrix. Therefore $-1$ is an eigenvalue. That is, there is a non trivial solution to $(A-(-1)I)x=(A+I)x=0$. Thus $\det{(A+I)}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: This is a totally non-mathematical solution, but whatever:
If you multiple choice and they say only one is true (and if they're not lying), you can just build an example and see what happens, for example: $-I$ could be the matrix $A$, as it's determinant is $<0$, and $-I(-I)^t=I$. and obviously $det(-I+I)=0$, so the correct answer is b).

That's a trick you can use in an exam if you're running out of time and you can't build a proper solution (and that's why I think multiple choice exams are totally unfair).

Comment: But we are talking $10 \times 10$ matrices, so $\det(-I) = 1$, right?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti You're right.